# What is the input format for sk-learn classifiers?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to both scikit and numpy/pandas, but I am familiar with Python and data processing in general. I am confused about what format the inputs to sk-learn classifiers should be. I have tried using a debugger to inspect example matrices used in tutorial examples of sk-learn, but they have a huge number of members and I can't figure out which ones are the data and which are derived.

Is there a reference specification somewhere that explains what an array must look like and how to construct it for it to be a valid input for sk-learn classifiers?

Comment: Start here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html

Comment: [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/), [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) and [sk-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html) references are here. You can start inspecting and learning by following their tutorials. sk-learn classifiers have different requirements for different algorithms.

Comment: @Prateek How do you read "Is there a reference specification" and conclude that I am asking for opinion?

Comment: @HarvIpan Yes, buried somewhere in those hundreds of pages is surely the answer to my question. Feel free to post a specific link if you know where it is.

Comment: @user8493571 your question is too broad to be answered. There are many classifiers within sklearn . You need to go through documentation or see the sklearn source codes OR [edit] your question to specific sklearn classifier. I hope *Harv Ipan* echoed the same thing here.

Comment: @Prateek actually sk-learn classifiers all use a common interface, so there's just one format that needs to be documented.

Comment: @user8493571 I started using sklearn couple of weeks back. ran into same problem. It's cumbersome to come up with our own common interface..I have kept that project aside for a while now. Seems would take time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sklearn expects your feature matrix `X` to have the following form:

```
ind feat1   feat2
0   2   1
1   1   2
```

You can use either pandas Dataframes or numpy arrays for inputs.

If you are using classified learning then `y` needs to have as many rows as `X`.

You can load datasets from sklearn, and check the dimensions and shapes of the matrices because already fit right into problem-related algorithms (in this case it would be a supervised regression problem):

```
import sklearn.datasets
X,y = sklearn.datasets.load_boston(return_X_y=True)
X.shape[0] == y.shape[0]
```

Output

```
True
```